# Lifetime of eMMC device

Tags: boot, storage, embedded

I have better knowledge about the NAND and NOR memory devices as I'm currently working with them. Now I have heard that eMMC device is going to be used in one of my upcoming project.
What is the assured lifetime(write or erase cycles) of eMMC device compared to conventional NOR and NAND flashes?

Answer (score 2):

A [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_memory_cards) lists 1 million read/write cycles for eMMC flash memory, and lists the comparisons you ask for.

This question is now extremely important for a second reason.  A new line of laptops (eg, HP stream 13 or Chromebook) is using 32GB eMMC in lieu of a hard drive.  With a fixed read/write cycle, these seem to be "disposable" laptops that you can only use for a while before their main storage just stops working, especially if the eMMC unit is not replaceable, or cannot be restored from system restore or backup media.